# Fedora 18: can't resolve hosts

Tags: fedora, dns

My Fedora 18 machine is having problems with resolving hosts:

`Could not resolve host: ...; No address associated with hostname]`

`HTTP error on [https://lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens], curl code [6] message [Could not resolve host: lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com; No address associated with hostname]'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Would be nice if you could elaborate a bit more. Is it a valid host you are trying to resolve? which util do you use to resolve the host (`host google.com`)? Is your network interface up (`ip addr`)?

Comment: It is also important to have the content of /etc/resolve.conf and maybe /etc/hosts.

Comment: Are you having trouble resolving every host with every program or just rackspacecloud.com using `curl`?  Can you `ping google.com`?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely that the file `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't have any entries for DNS servers to resolve hostname or IP addresses against.

Here is a basic file:

```
# Google DNS servers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

You can use the text editors `gedit` (GUI) or `nano` (command line) to edit this file and add these lines to it. You'll need to be root to edit this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to reach any website, there may be problems with the DNS servers that you've configured.  These are found in `/etc/resolv.conf` and are set by NetworkManager when it connects to a network.  If you manually change them, they may be overwritten the next time you connect to a network.  You can edit the file to troubleshoot other nameservers, but the best way to make permanent changes to your DNS servers is to use System Settings.

Navigate to System Settings -> Network -> Wireless (or Wired).  If you are connected via Wifi, select the wireless network you are connected to from the drop down.  Press the "Options" button (you may have to disconnect from the network for this button to be enabled).  In the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs, the method should be Automatic DHCP, meaning the network you are connecting to will provide your IP address, netmask, gateway, and DNS servers.  Try entering a public DNS server (such as Google's: 8.8.8.8) in the "Additional DNS Servers" field for both the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs and reconnecting to the network.

Verify the new DNS server is in `/etc/resolv.conf` and try connecting to a website again.